# The caption package interferes with the showexpl package

Tags: sectioning, captions, incompatibility, examples, showexpl

When the `caption` package is loaded, it messes up the cross-referencing of listings typeset using the `showexpl` package. The `\ref` command prints the number of the section in which the `LTXexample` is located, rather than the number of the listing itself. The same effect does not occur when using the `lstlisting` environment. Examples of both are given in the minimal working example below.

Does anyone know how to fix this, so that the `LTXexample` listings can be referenced by number rather than section?

## Minimal working example

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing only using the \texttt{lstlisting} environment.},label={example1}]
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection{Consectetuer adipiscing elit}

\verb|\ref{example1}| yields ``\ref{example1}'', which is correct.

\section{Ut purus elit}

\subsection{Vestibulum ut}

\begin{LTXexample}[caption={Listing and output using \texttt{LTXexample} environment.},label={example2}]
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[caption={Another example of code and output.}, label={example3}]
  \lipsum[1][3]
\end{LTXexample}

\subsection{Placerat ac}

\verb|\ref{example2}| yields ``\ref{example2}'' instead of ``2''.

\verb|\ref{example3}| yields ``\ref{example3}'' instead of ``3''.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Does `LTXexample` support `label=` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change to `tcolorbox` instead of `listings+showexpl`. `listings` tcolorbox library includes tools to easily show `LaTeX` code and results.

What follows is just an example with `default` tcolorboxes format. But it can be easily changed to desired design.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showexpl}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{myonlylisting}[3][]{%
    title=Listing~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    label=#3,
    listing only,
    #1
}

\newtcblisting[use counter from=myonlylisting]{mylisting}[3][]{%
    title=Listing~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    label=#3,
    text side listing,
    #1 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{myonlylisting}{Listing only using the \texttt{lstlisting} environment.}{example1}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{myonlylisting}

\subsection{Consectetuer adipiscing elit}

\verb|\ref{example1}| yields ``\ref{example1}'', which is correct.

\section{Ut purus elit}

\subsection{Vestibulum ut}

\begin{mylisting}{Listing and output using \texttt{LTXexample} environment.}{example2}
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}{Another example of code and output.}{example3}
  \lipsum[1][3]
\end{mylisting}

\subsection{Placerat ac}

\verb|\ref{example2}| yields ``\ref{example2}'' instead of ``2''.

\verb|\ref{example3}| yields ``\ref{example3}'' instead of ``3''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Following code produces an style similar to original design.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mystyle/.style={
        empty,
        coltitle=black,
        halign title=center,
        listing options={numbers=left, numberstyle={\tiny}, numbersep=2mm},
        size=fbox,
    }
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{myonlylisting}[3][]{%
    mystyle,
    title=Listing~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    label=#3,
    listing only,
    #1,
}

\newtcblisting[use counter from=myonlylisting]{mylisting}[3][]{%
    mystyle,
    title=Listing~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    label=#3,
    text side listing,
    leftlower=5mm,
    overlay={\draw (interior.north west) rectangle (segmentation.south);
        },
    #1 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{myonlylisting}{Listing only using the \texttt{lstlisting} environment.}{example1}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{myonlylisting}

\subsection{Consectetuer adipiscing elit}

\verb|\ref{example1}| yields ``\ref{example1}'', which is correct.

\section{Ut purus elit}

\subsection{Vestibulum ut}

\begin{mylisting}{Listing and output using \texttt{LTXexample} environment.}{example2}
\lipsum[1][2]
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}{Another example of code and output.}{example3}
\lipsum[1][3]
\end{mylisting}

\subsection{Placerat ac}

\verb|\ref{example2}| yields ``\ref{example2}'' instead of ``2''.

\verb|\ref{example3}| yields ``\ref{example3}'' instead of ``3''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `showexpl` keys don't include `label`.

Place `\label` in the argument to `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={Listing only using the \texttt{lstlisting} environment.},
  label={example1}
]
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection{Consectetuer adipiscing elit}

\verb|\ref{example1}| yields ``\ref{example1}'', which is correct.

\section{Ut purus elit}

\subsection{Vestibulum ut}

\begin{LTXexample}[
  caption={Listing and output using \texttt{LTXexample} environment.\label{example2}}
]
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[caption={Another example of code and output.\label{example3}}]
  \lipsum[1][3]
\end{LTXexample}

\subsection{Placerat ac}

\verb|\ref{example2}| yields ``\ref{example2}'' instead of ``2''.

\verb|\ref{example3}| yields ``\ref{example3}'' instead of ``3''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I could get it to work for this example, but the same problem persisted when I tried it in a larger document with more `LTXexample`s.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but I can't see why it would fail.